Different Periods in Wireshark for Reading and Writing Registers on Modbus using ST Language in TwinCAT3
I have a program for reading and writing Modbus data in TwinCAT 3. The task cycle is set to 13 ms. Upon observing Wireshark logs, I noticed that the period for reading data is approximately 25 ms, whereas the period for writing data is around 50 ms.
IF NOT fbmbreadregs.bBusy THEN
    fbMBReadRegs(
        sIPAddr:= '192.168.2.20', 
        nTCPPort:= 1504, 
        nUnitID:= 16#FF, 
        nQuantity:= 14, 
        nMBAddr:= 0, 
        cbLength:= SIZEOF(st_ModbusRead), 
        pDestAddr:= ADR(st_ModbusRead), 
        bExecute:= TRUE, 
        tTimeout:= , 
        bBusy=> , 
        bError=> , 
        nErrId=> , 
        cbRead=> );
    
    
    
    fbBasicPID(
        fSetpointValue:= 50,
        fActualValue:= st_ModbusRead.SOC, 
        bReset:= FALSE, 
        fCtrlCycleTime:=0.013 , 
        fKp:= 0.00005, 
        fTn:= 1, 
        fTv:= 0, 
        fTd:= 0, 
        fCtrlOutput=> nFout, 
        nErrorStatus=>);
    
            
    nPref:=(1/0.001)*(50-nFout);
    
    
ELSE
    fbMBReadRegs(bExecute:= FALSE);
END_IF



IF NOT fbMBWriteRegs.bBusy  THEN
        
        arrPQ[0]:=REAL_TO_WORD(ABS(nPref));
        
    fbMBWriteRegs(
        sIPAddr:= '192.168.2.20', 
        nTCPPort:= 1504, 
        nUnitID:= 16#FF, 
        nQuantity:= 5, 
        nMBAddr:= 16#0014, 
        cbLength:= SIZEOF(arrPQ), 
        pSrcAddr:= ADR(arrPQ), 
        bExecute:= TRUE, 
        tTimeout:= , 
        bBusy=> , 
        bError=> , 
        nErrId=> );

ELSE
    fbMBWriteRegs(bExecute:=FALSE);
END_IF

Why do these periods differ? How can I achieve the same period for both read and write operations?

You could probably achieve this by synchronizing bExecute inputs of fbMBWriteRegs and fbMBReadRegs by doing something like that:
fbTON100ms(PT := T#100MS);
IF bRedgeEvery100ms  THEN 
    bRedgeEvery100ms := FALSE; 
    fbTON100ms.IN := TRUE; 
END_IF;
IF fbTON100ms.Q AND (NOT fbmbreadregs.bBusy) AND (NOT fbMBWriteRegs.bBusy) 
THEN
    fbTON100ms.IN := FALSE;
    bRedgeEvery100ms := TRUE;
END_IF
fbMBReadRegs(
        sIPAddr:= '192.168.2.20', 
        nTCPPort:= 1504, 
        nUnitID:= 16#FF, 
        nQuantity:= 14, 
        nMBAddr:= 0, 
        cbLength:= SIZEOF(st_ModbusRead), 
        pDestAddr:= ADR(st_ModbusRead), 
        bExecute:= bRedgeEvery100ms, 
        tTimeout:= , 
        bBusy=> , 
        bError=> , 
        nErrId=> , 
        cbRead=> );
        
fbMBWriteRegs(
        sIPAddr:= '192.168.2.20', 
        nTCPPort:= 1504, 
        nUnitID:= 16#FF, 
        nQuantity:= 5, 
        nMBAddr:= 16#0014, 
        cbLength:= SIZEOF(arrPQ), 
        pSrcAddr:= ADR(arrPQ), 
        bExecute:= bRedgeEvery100ms, 
        tTimeout:= , 
        bBusy=> , 
        bError=> , 
        nErrId=> );

But since, as far as I know, modbus communication on TwinCat uses separate windows process that communicates with PLC runtime asynchronically - you do not have 100% control over modbus telegrams execution.
Alternative option that might work for some usecases - let Modbus communication be as it is, but create another pair of variables like st_ModbusReadSync  and arrPQSync and update them synchronously like
IF bRedgeEvery100ms THEN
  st_ModbusReadSync := st_ModbusRead;
  arrPQ := arrPQSync;
END_IF

Also, putting fbBasicPID inside IF NOT fbmbreadregs.bBusy THEN seems like a bad idea to me. I do not have experience with this exact interpretation of PID-regulator, but usually they should be executed in every cycle without interruptions.
